# How to loop in JSON array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I call an ajax function to get some information from the server. Server-side return a JSON array like below.

```
[{id:1,name:"somename"},{id:5,name:"someanothername"}]
```

and I want to loop this array

```
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "/Search/SearchNews",
        type: "POST",
        cache: true,
        async: true,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {

            for (var i = 0; i < result.lenght; i++) {
                    console.log(result[i].name);
                }

            }

    });
```

but it does not work. when I call "`console.log(result.lenght)` it will return `undefined`

how can I loop this array.

Comment: you noticed the typo in `length`, did you?

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/9j46oa1a/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try spelling LENGTH correctly: `result.lenght` should be: `result.length`

Comment: You are so right:) it is my bad and  I was killing myself for hours

Comment: i will delete this question :)

Comment: @OzanErtürk Time for a coffee break!